# How to receive/fetch url parameter (get request) in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, get, request, flutter-web

I am using a script by exporting it with flutter for the web.
There I need to put something over an URL slug into a field via a get request.

Example:

```
www.url.de/?id=123
```

here I need to put "123" into the field.

How can I read this 123 out of the URL with Flutter Web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Uri.base.queryParameters` it returns a Map, so you can do `Uri.base.queryParameters['id']` and it will return the value